# R. Multivariate linear regression iterating column-wise over pairs of variables

Tags: r, linear-regression

I have a dataframe dfA (the real one has 1000 rows and 400,000 columns). From column 6 on, the variable names are "triads" formed by x with + different prefixes (GT_x, N_x, E_x), where x = rs1, rs7, rs300, rs502, etc:

```
ID    SEX    PV    GAN    GAE    GT_rs1    N_rs1    E_rs1    GT_rs7    N_rs7    E_rs7    ...
2    0    7.8    0.3    0.4    0    1    1    1    0    2    ...
6    1    6.4    0.35    0.55    0    0    1    1    1    2    ...
```

Here is a reproducible example of my data:

```
dfA = data.frame(rbind(c("ID","SEX","PV","GAN","GAE","GT_rs1","N_rs1","E_rs1","GT_rs7","N_rs7","E_rs7"), 
                   c(2,0,7.8,0.3,0.4,0,1,1,1,0,2),
                   c(6,1,6.4,0.35,0.55,0,0,1,1,1,2)))
dfA = dfA %>% row_to_names(row_number = 1)
```

Using R, I want to run a linear regression of the form:

```
lm(PV ~ SEX + GAN + GT_x + N_x)
```

where x is rs1, rs7 and so on. So, I'd need to iterate column-wise over pairs of variables. I would like to get estimate, std.error, statistic and p.value for the different covariates (SEX, GAN, GT_x and N_x). SEX = categorical variable; PV, GAN = quantitative variables; GT_x, N_x, E_x = additive variables.

Comment: Could you add reproducible data with `dput(dfA)`? It would be enough to have the columns for computing a couple of distinct `lm`s (for example `PV, SEX, GAN, GT_rs1, N_rs1, GT_rs7, N_rs7`) and also enough rows to get results.

Comment: Do you want `E_x` in the model or not?

Comment: Hi @GregorThomas. No, thanks

Comment: Hi @iago, I just added reproducible data. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build formulas by pasting together strings - we just need to know the strings you want to paste together.

This should work - it's untested because the data you share isn't shared with `dput` so it's not copy/pasteable, and it only has one set of covariates so it doesn't illustrate the complexity of the problem. If you have issues, please share copy/pasteable data to illustrate and I'll try to debug.

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(broom)
# get all unique strings after underscores from your column names
suffix = str_extract(names(dfA), "_.*") %>% na.omit %>% unique
prefix = c("GT", "N")
base_formula = "PV ~ SEX + GAN +"
full_formula = paste(base_formula, paste0(prefix[1], suffix), "+", paste0(prefix[2], suffix))

mods = list()
for(i in seq_along(full_formula)) {
  mods[[suffix[i]]] = lm(as.formula(full_formula[i]), data = dfA)
}

stats = lapply(mods, tidy)
stats = bind_rows(stats, .id = "suffix")
```

Answer (score 2):

Here a solution with `purrr` in one simple pipeline.

You just need to create a list of `GT_x` and `N_x` to use. You can do it by using some regex.

```
library(purrr)

nn <- names(df)
pattern <- "^GT_|^N_"

vars <- nn[grepl(pattern, nn)] # get the variables that start with GT_ and N_
x <- sub(pattern, "", vars)    # get every x

split(vars, x) %>%
 map(paste, collapse = " + ") %>% 
 sprintf("PV ~ SEX + GAN + %s", .) %>% 
 map(lm, data = df) %>% 
 map_dfr(broom::tidy, .id = "model")
```

This returns a unique Dataframe. Each model is identified by the column `model`.
If you prefer a list just replace `map_dfr` with `map` and remove `.id`.

---

Here I created a reproducible example of your data:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(ID = 1:1000,
                 SEX = sample(0:1, 1000, replace = TRUE),
                 PV  = rnorm(1000),
                 GAN = rnorm(1000),
                 GAE = rnorm(1000))
newcols <- unlist(lapply(c("GT_rs", "N_rs", "E_rs"), paste0, sample(100, 50)))
df[newcols] <- replicate(50, rnorm(1000))

df
```

Comment: Thank you @Edo. As iago points out, the problem with your solution is that assumes an arithmetic sequence, which is not.

Comment: Just replace seq_len(n) with any numeric vector you want. Like c(1,2,7,102,306). It will work anyway

Comment: Or you don’t know the numbers and you need to find them?

Comment: Thank you @Edo. I don't know the numbers

Comment: I edited the answer. Now with the new edit you can see that you don't need anymore to know the numbers. It works even if one of GT or N is missing.

Answer (score 1):

Since Edo has edited its solution, I add my variant of it:

```r
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(broom)

list("GT_rs", "N_rs") %>% 
    map(~dfA %>%  
             select(matches(paste0(.x,"\\d+"))) %>% 
             names %>% 
             sub(pattern = .x, replacement = "")) %>% 
    reduce(intersect) %>% # until here we get the variables GT_rsx, N_rsx
    sprintf("PV ~ SEX + GAN + GT_rs%s + N_rs%s", ., .) %>%
    map(lm, data = dfA) %>%
    map_dfr(tidy, .id = "model") %>% 
    group_by(model) %>% 
    mutate(suffix = sub("N_rs", "", term[grepl("^N_rs\\d+$", term)]))
```

Comment: Thanks @iago !. Your solution is very good. May I ask, in the last step, how to replace  the IDs of the "model" column with the N_rs ID instead?. Many thanks

Comment: @Lucas I updated the answer to get a column `suffix` with the `N_rs` IDs